# Android Studio bringing back deleted and removed modules with empty folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I removed 2 modules from project and deleted files from physical folder but AS bringing them back over and over again with a folder that containing .iml files.

I cleaned, rebuilt, deleted build folder and rebuilt it again, invalidated cache and restart but they are back again. How should i remove these modules for good? In image modules with blue square badges are the ones should not exist but they do.

[image: Android Studio Modules]

Answer (score 5):

Check if the libs exists in below mentioned files and remove entries:

1. `build.gradle` in app folder
2. `settings.gradle` in root folder

Then remove lib folders manually. Finally rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Structure and select the modules and click on red minus button top of the dialog and Click ok mention right bottom of dialog.

Comment: I already did that. I removed modules and they keep coming back.

Comment: then check it is available in settings.gradle and if yes then remove from it